# Слайдер на JavaScript

Tags: javascript, slider

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю неправильно.
Мне нужно сделать управляемый цикличный слайдер. То есть после последнего слайда должен появляться первый и наоборот. У меня же получается, что последний слайд исчезает и ничего больше после него не появляется. Ниже приведен код.

```
var images = document.getElementsByClassName("photos");
var next = document.getElementById("next");
var prev = document.getElementById("prev");
var i = 0;


next.addEventListener("click", moveRight);

function moveRight() {
    images[i].style.display = "none";
    images[++i].style.display = "block";
    if(i > images.length)
        i = 0;
}

prev.addEventListener("click", moveLeft);

function moveLeft() {
    images[i].style.display = "none";
    images[--i].style.display = "block";
    if(i == 0)
        i = images.length - 1;
}
```

Очень прошу помочь!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте сделать вот так

```
var images = document.getElementsByClassName("photos");
var next = document.getElementById("next");
var prev = document.getElementById("prev");
var i = 0;
var length = images.length;


next.addEventListener("click", moveRight);

function moveRight() {
    if(i == length-1){
            images[0].style.display = "block";
            images[i].style.display = "none";
            i = 0;
        } else{
            images[i+1].style.display = "block";
            images[i].style.display = "none";
            i++;
        }
}

prev.addEventListener("click", moveLeft);

function moveLeft() {
    if(i == 0){
        images[length-1].style.display = "block";
        images[i].style.display = "none";
        i = length-1;
    } else{
        images[i-1].style.display = "block";
        images[i].style.display = "none";
        i--;
    }
```